# How can I access Active Record classes to create records from a module/class in the lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4.2 app. I want to create a script in the lib folder that I will use to create records in my database. So hypothetically:

`lib/user_builder.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require './app/models/application_record.rb'
require './app/models/client.rb'

module UserTheory
  class UserBuilder
    def initialize
      user = User.find_or_initialize_by(id: 1)
      user.name = 'Bob'
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

I required those files because I was getting NameErrors about those classes. Now I am getting another error:

`` /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in `retrieve_connection': No connection pool for User (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished) ``

so clearly I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: instead of putting it in `lib`, try a directory inside `app/` such as `app/services`. Then you shouldn't need the requires and autoloading should work properly.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `db/seeds.rb` file?

Comment: Actually, you can use rake tasks to do your case

Comment: `db/seeds.rb` is the way to go here.